# JMeter - Opening multiple websocket connections in parallel

Tags: websocket, jmeter

The application that I am testing has multiple WebSocket sub-protocols. So, is there a way to open multiple websocket connections in parallel using JMeter?

My current test plan looks like this:

```
Thread Group
  \_ Websocket Open connection 1 (with subprotocol 1)
  \_ Websocket request-response samplers
  \_ Websocket Open connection 2 (with subprotocol 2)
  \_ Websocket request-response samplers
```

But when I open connection 2, connection 1 is automatically closed. I am looking for some way to hold both open simultaneously. Any help is appreciated!

Please note that I am using Peter Doornbosch's JMeter WebSocket Samplers (from https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When **WebSocket Open Connection** sampler is invoked it instantiates [WebSocketClient](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/luminis/websocket/WebSocketClient.java) establishing the connection with the backend and puts the instance into [Thread-Local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) storage

If there is an active connection at this phase - it will be [closed](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/07c89ab55f7b03cd4627a44d752a1db67eeaf3d3/src/main/java/eu/luminis/jmeter/wssampler/OpenWebSocketSampler.java#lines-44).

So you cannot have > 1 websocket connection for 1 JMeter Thread (virtual user)

The options are in:

1. Just remove `Websocket Open connection 2 (with subprotocol 2)` along with its `Websocket request-response samplers` and parameterize `subprotocol` using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so 1st virtual user will establish connection with `subprotocol 1` and 2nd virtual user will go for `subprotocol 2`
2. Put your construction under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)

Not knowing the full context it's hard to recommend something, personally I would go for option 1

Comment: Thanks, but as per my use case all users have to go through both sub protocols. I will look into Parallel Controller and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Guys, With jmeter websocket Can I open multiple connections based on the virtual ip addresses on Jemeter machine. For example if my jmeter machine has 50 IP addressed and I want to open separate connection for each IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the (experimental) multi-connection support that is available on a separate branch, see https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/multiple-connections/. The readme explains how to use it. You'll have to build the plugin yourself, but that's fairly easy and also documented in the readme.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out.